# How can I delete child rows when I delete a parent row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdminTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AdminTestId] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Test_ExamId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[AdminTest]([ExamId] ASC);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTestQuestion] (
    [AdminTestQuestionId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AdminTestId]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdminTestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AdminTestQuestionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AdminTestQuestionAdminTestId] FOREIGN KEY ([AdminTestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AdminTest] ([AdminTestId])
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AdminTestQuestion_AdminTestId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[AdminTestQuestion]([AdminTestId] ASC);
```

Is there some way that I can change the definition of the tables so that when I delete a row from AdminTest then all the child rows in AdminTestQuestions for that test are deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your foreign key constraint;

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_AdminTestQuestionAdminTestId] 
  FOREIGN KEY ([AdminTestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AdminTest] ([AdminTestId])
  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b63d9/1).

I may not need to point out that this is not necessarily a good idea in the long run, since it will make implicit changes to your data that other users may not know about. Use with caution.

Comment: This will propagate delete operations from child table to parent, but what happens when A record is deleted in Parent table?

Comment: @M.Ali No, it will propagate from the parent to the child that has the constraint. If the parent is deleted, the child is deleted too. For example, [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84375/1) shows that the parent remains when a child is deleted, while the fiddle in the answer shows propagation parent->child.